# Angular FirebaseUI Auth via Twitter, GitHub, Microsoft Not Working

Tags: angular, firebase, authentication, firebaseui

I'm trying to setup Angular (v11) app with FirebaseUI auth via different providers, following steps provided [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/firebaseui#oauth_providers_google_facebook_twitter_and_github).

The only one that works for me is Google. Others I'm trying all give various errors:

- Twitter: "Callback URL not approved for this client application. Approved callback URLs can be adjusted in your application settings"
- GitHub: "Unable to process request due to missing initial state. This may happen if browser sessionStorage is inaccessible or accidentally cleared"
- Microsoft: "The provided value for the input parameter 'redirect_uri' is not valid"

However, I followed the steps & configured API keys & callback URL in the respective platforms per Firebase instructions (using the callback Firebase shows when you enable each sign-in method).  The only one not so sure I did properly is Microsoft, but the others were pretty straight forward.

This is the [published page](https://bitofgaia.com/) in case you want to see the behavior.

This is the [code repo](https://github.com/benm5678/Angular-FirebaseUI-Auth) -- the main files where I implemented the logic are in [auth.service.ts](https://github.com/benm5678/Angular-FirebaseUI-Auth/blob/master/src/app/auth/auth.service.ts) & [login.component.ts](https://github.com/benm5678/Angular-FirebaseUI-Auth/blob/master/src/app/components/login/login.component.ts) (I hid the apiKey/appId in firebaseConfig, since not sure if it's sensitive).

Anyone had luck with it & perhaps has some tip?  Thanks!!

Comment: You should always share the source code when asking questions on Stack Overflow.  Without that, we can't be of much help.  Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @doug-stevenson I added links to source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally got it to work.  It appears the callback URL it suggests you use in Firebase is wrong.  See this example from one of the platforms: [image].
To make it work I had to remove the "-default-rtdb" (so correct callback in this case is: "https://bit-of-gaia.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler")

Comment: Had the same thing with github and a custom domain. Even if youre using a custom domain with firebase, it seems you need to use `yourproject.firebaseapp.com` as the hostname for oauth callbacks

Comment: I got the same problem but with Facebook, this does not solve it. Any suggestions?

Comment: In my case, I was using GitHub provider with custom domain.
Although GitHub configuration in firebase console tells me to use the default redirect URL(eg. abc-989d.firebaseapp.com) not the custom one I had created. But that was causing the error in question.

Once I updated my GitHub application with the new custom URL everything worked fine.

Eg: `https://auth.custom-domain.com/__/auth/handler` this is what I've set in app configuration on GitHub.