# Flutter Twitter Auth Error, Missing InitialState

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

Recently i started with a Twitter Integration.

The callback is working as it should.
[image: Login_Twitter]

but when i press the **Authorize App** i keep receiving this error.

> unable to process request due to missing initial state. this may happen if browser sessionstorage is inaccesible or accidentally cleared

[image: Error_Login]

This is the function where i call the twitter_login.

```
@override
  Future<FbUser> signInWithTwitter(
      Function(AuthException) exceptionCallback) async {
    var me;
    final twitterLogin = TwitterLogin(
        apiKey: 'xxxxxxxxx',
        apiSecretKey: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        redirectURI: 'https://volado-app.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler');
    // Trigger the sign-in flow
    try {
      final authResult = await twitterLogin.login();
      switch (authResult.status) {
        case TwitterLoginStatus.loggedIn:
          final twitterAuthProvider = TwitterAuthProvider.credential(
              accessToken: authResult.authToken,
              secret: authResult.authTokenSecret);
          final userCredential = await FirebaseAuth.instance
              .signInWithCredential(twitterAuthProvider);
          return userFromFirebase(userCredential.user);
          break;
        case TwitterLoginStatus.cancelledByUser:
          exceptionCallback(AuthException(
              code: authResult.status.toString(),
              message: 'login canceled by user'));
          break;
        case TwitterLoginStatus.error:
          print(authResult.errorMessage);
          exceptionCallback(AuthException(
              code: authResult.status.toString(), message: 'Error login'));
          break;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      exceptionCallback(
          AuthException(code: e.errorCode, message: 'Unknown error'));
    }
    return me;
    // Get the Logged In session
  }
```

on my **AndroidManifest** i have this inside my activity tag

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "example://gizmos” -->
            <!-- Registered Callback URLs in TwitterApp -->
            <data android:host="volado-app.firebaseapp.com" /> <!-- host is option -->
        </intent-filter>
```

i search and the only thing almost close was this:

[Angular FirebaseUI Auth via Twitter, GitHub, Microsoft Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65261848/angular-firebaseui-auth-via-twitter-github-microsoft-not-working)

But the issue was for angular, and the url i don't see any problem of misspelling :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some hours trying to figure out the problem, i found that the issue was on the **AndroidManifest.xml**

Basically on the intent-filter, the scheme was missing, and i need to remove the https from the host and the function call. After that it work :)

```
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="https"
                        android:host="volado-app.firebaseapp.com" />
            </intent-filter>
```

Comment: where add these lines in AndroidManifest.xml